# Stats preview frontendmentor

Tags: html, css

So im stuck on getting the h3 elements to line up side by side
like they do in the picture right i have no styling
only three h3 elements right underneath each other

```
<h3 class="1"> 10k+</h3>
<h3 class="2">314 </h3>
<h3 class="3">12M+</h3>
```

how do i get it like the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXglu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>first</h3>
  <h3>second</h3>
  <h3>third</h3>
</div>
```

Wrap them in a div and give that div `display: flex;` and `flex-direction-row;`

Comment: how do i get the text nice and concise like in the photo with the two columns

Comment: @codeoflulu i can't get the full work done for you, i gave you the hint it can be done with flexbox, if you want to learn about flexbox check this out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/